# Materialize select issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, materialize, dropdown

Hi All,
I'm struggling on finding ways to make the Materialize select issue/bug to be fixed on the system I'm developing.

Here are the things I tried:

1. Used `material_select();` after I set a value 
   E.g:
   `$('select#id').val('1').material_select();`
2. Checked if there's a selected index / item / value 
   E.g: 
   a. `$('select#id').val();`
   b. `$('select#id').filter(':selected').text();`
3. Add `class="browser-default"` so I don't have to initialize `material_select();`

All of this did not fixed my issue.

**Problem:**

- The materialize dropdown doesn't display the selected value even it has a value when I `console.log` it. [See picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/212Mo.png)
- Second pic displays the value and text of the dropdown in picture 1. [See picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKJub.png)

  **Others:**
  Materialize version: Materialize v0.100.2
  JQuery version: JQuery-3.2.1
  Browser: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

  Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know this API, but #1 seems suspect.

Comment: after set value you have to again initialize material_select();

Comment: @AZinkey - Hi, already did that. See #1. $('select#id').val('1').material_select()

Comment: @AluanHaddad Hi, I'm using REST API

Comment: @KylSanAntonio I meant the API of the material select widget.

Comment: Can you add your source code in post?